# Refused to execute script from because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable

Tags: express, socket.io, webrtc

I have webRTC working locally using socket.io and express. I moved the code to AWS server and now I get the following error below. I have been Googling it for 3 days and it is still not fix yet.

Error message:
Refused to execute script from 
    'http://myipaddress:3000/node_modules/socket.io/lib/socket.io.js' 
because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

My index.html file is set up as so.

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
       <title> WebRTC </title>
       <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
   </head>
```

Thanks for your help in advanced,
Regards,
Teli

Comment: Seems like js file is missing or the path is incorrect resulting to 404 error which entually generates/redirects to 404 error page(text/html)

Comment: show how you use `socket.io` in your NodeJS server

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Express js as your server then no need to worry about this.

Make a directory called public or whatever you want to call it and move all CSS, js files into it.

And put this line into your server script file.

```
 var app = express();
 app.use(express.static('public'));
```

It will serve all static files inside the public folder structure,

If you have any more doubts please [watch this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8lY9u3JFr5I)